# Prolog predicate (division) that calculate the expression

Tags: prolog

Write a Prolog predicate (division) that calculate the expression (C=A/B) and write the result, where B should not equal 0, A&B should be inputted from the user by using read predicate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - this looks like a copy & paste from homework and usually your advisors have given them to you to practice what you learned. Can you explain how you are approaching the topic? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Perhaps one tip: separate the I./O from the computation. Use a predicate `division/3` such that `division(A,B,C)` only succeeds for B different from 0. A second predicate `main` then just arranges the `read` and `write` goals around `division`. Note that `main` does not need arguments because it reads from the keyboard.

Comment: yes that’s right , but i can’t write this program can you help me ?!

Comment: Because i wrote an app but not working , i can’t realize it

Comment: i have stuck because i made simple app can’t solve this question ! hellppp 

Comment: You can edit your question with the code you have. Also the first step to a question is to actually ask a question. Do you have a syntex error and don't know why? Is the program sometimes working but not always? If you explain what you are looking for there's a good chance you will get help. Please also have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/1109583) about homework questions which explains a bit why people usually don't just write your homework for you.

Comment: Btw. have you tried my proposal to divide the work? Could you solve one of the two subtasks?

Answer (score 2):

This is a reified variant of the exercise:

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

main :-
    write('Enter a: '),
    read(A),
    write('Enter b: '),
    read(B),
    if_( X^division_(A,B,C,X),
         format('Result: ~f',[C]),
         write('Division by zero.')).


division_(_A, B, _C, false) :-
    0 is B.
division_(A, B, C, true) :-
    B =\= 0,
    C is A / B.
```

Comment: a: `1`, b: `0+0`

Comment: Indeed B has to be evaluated. Thank you!

Comment: As is, this does not work. First, `B is 0` should be `0 is B`, as only the right-hand side of `(is)/2` is evaluated. Second, what is `NormalB`? Shouldn't this just be `B` (after being checked with `B =\= 0`)?

Comment: You are completely right - I quickly added the constraint without testing. Will fix asap.